# How to enable Vuforia's lighting estimation in native iOS when I use SceneKit and ARKit?

Tags: scenekit, vuforia, arkit, lighting

I am writing Scene Node in SCNScene for a VuforiaEAGLView.

```
 fileprivate func createMyScene(with view: VuforiaEAGLView) -> SCNScene {
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "Models.scnassets/sun/DAE_SUN.dae")
    guard scene != nil else {
        print("Scene can't be load")
        return SCNScene()
    }

    boxMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.lightGray

    let omniLightNode = SCNNode()
    omniLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    omniLightNode.light?.type = .omni
    omniLightNode.light?.color = UIColor(white: 0.75, alpha: 1.0)
    omniLightNode.position = SCNVector3(x:50, y:50, z:50)
    scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(omniLightNode)

    let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
    ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    ambientLightNode.light?.type = .ambient
    ambientLightNode.light?.color = UIColor(white: 0.87, alpha: 1.0)
    scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

    let spotLightNode = SCNNode()
    spotLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    spotLightNode.light?.type = .spot
    spotLightNode.light?.color = UIColor(white: 0.87, alpha: 1.0)
    spotLightNode.position = SCNVector3(x:10, y:10, z:10)
    scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(spotLightNode)


    for node in (scene?.rootNode.childNodes)! {
        if node.name == "sun" {
            node.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
            node.scale = SCNVector3Make(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
        }
    }
    return scene!
}
```

However, the light is not right. And, I also wanna turn on lighting estimation by ARKit. I saw [Vuforia support says the new Vuforia SDK support ARKit lighting estimation](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/ground-plane/enabling-lighting-estimation). But, the supporter doesn't mention how to enable this feature.

Question: How to turn on the lighting estimation by ARKit in Vuforia?